# DNS/Internet Access Packet and Socket Traffic Issues (Ubuntu Studio-wired ethernet direct to Router)

Tags: networking, internet, dns, webserver, sockets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6DD8.png)

How can I fix this in Ubuntu Studio? (I am hard wired directly to router with ethernet wire, router has static external web ip from ISP):

```
user@user-MS-7693:~$ ping -c 10 google.com

ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

user@user-MS-7693:~$ ping -c 10 msn.com
ping: msn.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT3rW.png)

```
user@user-MS-7693:~$ ping -c 10 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=587 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=883 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=665 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=577 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=58 time=554 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=58 time=555 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=58 time=577 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=58 time=676 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=58 time=633 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=58 time=588 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9008ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 554.462/629.496/883.478/93.902 ms
user@user-MS-7693:~$
```

Comment: Your question did not mention where your DNS is located, whether it is on your network, provided by your ISP, or elsewhere on the wider internet.

Comment: Hello! thanks for the comment. Honestly I don't even know which one is the issue, wether its the DNS for my internal network that is the issue or the external ISP one. I would need help understanding the difference.....all I know is that I can't ping any external website, but I can ping 8.8.8.8 using the ping command in the terminal...

Comment: I just tried this today as well (Dig command) and I got this:  user@user-MS-7693:~$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

user@user-MS-7693:~$